# Setting up Firebase Crashlytics for iOS not working

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am trying to setup **Firebase Crashlytics**  and I followed the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) but it is not connecting. This keeps loading:

[image]

If I build & run my app and crash it, this is what I get in my console:

> [connection] nw_resolver_start_query_timer_block_invoke [C2] Query fired: did not receive all answers in time for firebase-settings.crashlytics.com:443
> (lldb)

I added the `pod`, called `Firebase.configure()` inside the `AppDelegate` and added this runscript:

[image]

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add GoogleService-Info.plist to your project?

Comment: @MikhailVasilev yes I have. Using Firebase is working fine. I just want to be able to use it inside my `Share Extension` as well and thats where I struggle

Comment: @Chris have you ever figured this out?

Comment: @masiton no :( I „fixed“ resetting the whole project and tried it again with a new Firebase Project and it suddenly worked. No idea what the issue was